# fail to migration from jboss as 6 to jboss eap 7.1 with -ds.xml configuration

Tags: java, jboss

this is the first time for question.
Please help me to solve this problem.

I've been completed to migration from AS6 to EAP7.1. but, It still has problem with -ds.xml

```
10:26:01,286 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "mySource.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"mySource.war\".FIRST_MODULE_USE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase FIRST_MODULE_USE of deployment \"mySource.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYJCA0064: Exception deploying datasource java:jboss/datasources/jt400
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty name segment is not allowed for jdbc-driver"}}
```

upper is the problem log when i tried to debug my source on the JBoss EAP 7.x.
and below is one of my jt400.xml file contents.

```
<datasource connectable="false" enabled="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/jt400" jta="true" pool-name="jt400" spy="false" use-ccm="true" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:as400://127.0.0.1</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver</driver-class>
    <datasource-class/>
    <driver/>
    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_NONE</transaction-isolation>
    <pool>
      <min-pool-size>0</min-pool-size>
      <initial-pool-size>0</initial-pool-size>
      <max-pool-size>30</max-pool-size>
      <prefill>false</prefill>
      <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
      <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
    </pool>
    <security>
      <user-name>sa</user-name>
      <password>sa</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
      <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT * FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1</check-valid-connection-sql>
      <use-fast-fail>false</use-fast-fail>
    </validation>
    <timeout>
      <blocking-timeout-millis>5000</blocking-timeout-millis>
      <idle-timeout-minutes>15</idle-timeout-minutes>
      <xa-resource-timeout>0</xa-resource-timeout>
    </timeout>
    <statement>
      <track-statements>false</track-statements>
    </statement>
  </datasource>
```

finally, I was copy the driver file (jt400.jar) into the standalone/lib path.

I don't have any idea to solve this problem...
Please anybody help me... It seriously headache for me haha...

Thankyou!

Comment: did you specify the `jdbc` driver in the xml?

Comment: Sorry for late reply.

Comment: I already solved this problem like your comment checking xml
I will share the way to solve this problem soon!

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is this line **driver**. It can't be empty, you need to define the driver. By example:

```
  <driver>mysql</driver>
```

and after the  just define the driver itself, in this example:

```
 <drivers>                    
    <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
       <driver-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
       <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
     </driver>
 </drivers>
```

If you add that area you will resolve the error message.

Comment: Yes! Your right!
So, I will share all way of solved problem soon!